# Is there any difference between estimating $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma$ in a simulation study?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, moments, invariance

In a simulation study, is there any difference between

$\bullet$ estimating the variance $\sigma^2$, $1000$ times and taking its average,
and

$\bullet$ estimating  the standard deviation $\sigma$, $1000$ times and taking its average?

Can I do anyone of these? Is there any preference of doing a particular one?

Comment: Clearly there's *some* differences because the variance and the standard deviation are not the same. Can you be more specific about what you're after?

Comment: We prefer the variance because the formula for variance is unbiased for any underlying distribution. You may find the answers to your question on this page https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249688/why-are-we-using-a-biased-and-misleading-standard-deviation-formula-for-sigma

Comment: @hugh are you sure unbiasedness should be the only criterion?

Comment: @Glen_b In this link http://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-7-34 (Table 1), I am not understanding why did authors estimate $\sigma_0$, $\sigma_1$ instead of $\sigma_0^2$, $\sigma_1^2$?

Comment: Also http://www.joophox.net/publist/methodology05.pdf, authors estimated $\sigma.$

Comment: You would take the root of the average of the variances and want to know if you should rather simulate the standard deviation directly, right?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch No, rather I would take root of the estimated variance and average all estimated standard deviation (i.e., standard error).

Answer (score 6):

I find this question of interest because it highlights the artificial nature of seeking unbiasedness above everything else. A few points:

- the variance $\sigma^2$ allows for an unbiased estimator, while the square root of that estimator $\hat\sigma_n$ [is biased](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11707/7224) [by Jensen's inequality];
- there is [no generic unbiased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) of $\sigma$ [generic meaning across all distributions];
- for a scale or location-scale family of distributions, since $\sigma$ is a scale, the expectation $\mathbb{E}^P[\hat\sigma_n]$ can be written as 
  $$\mathbb{E}^P[\hat\sigma]=c(P,n)\sigma$$
  where $n$ is the sample size and $P$ is the family of distributions. Hence bias can be corrected family-wise

Comment: I guess the real reason one often is pooling variance (and not standard deviation) is that (with normal distributed data) it leads to cleaner distribution theory (F-dist).