# Ratio of mean absolute deviation to standard deviation under normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Can someone show why the ratio is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ ?

Comment: Need to specify the conditions. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation says the condition is " X is a normally distributed random variable with expected value 0". Is it the same as yours?

Comment: missed "with expected value 0". It says you can find the answer from  Geary, R. C. (1935). The ratio of the mean deviation to the standard deviation as a test of normality. Biometrika, 27(3/4), 310–332.

Comment: I don't see why X needs to have expectation 0. MAD and standard deviation will not change if the mean shifts. Yes wiki gives a reference where essentially there is simply the conclusion, which is why I am putting the question here.

Comment: See small number correction and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249688/99274). It is the same problem.

Comment: Try differentiating the normal pdf $\phi(x)$ w.r.t. $x$ and then _stare_ at the result to figure out how it is relevant to filling in the missing steps in the following calculation: $$\operatorname{MAD}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|\phi(x)dx=2\int_0^\infty x\phi(x)dx=~\cdots ~= \sqrt{\frac 2\pi}$$ for a standard normal random variable. Then extend the calculation to a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable.

Comment: @Carl Your "this" link is irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: The comment by Dilip Sarwate is essentially the answer. 

For $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, after using the obvious change of variables $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}=t$, we have $$E|X-\mu|=\sigma \int_{\mathbb R}|t|\phi(t)\,dt$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate I do not find fault with your answer. The commonality for $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}$  is from SD$_{n=2}=\dfrac{|x_2-x_1|}{\sqrt{2}}$. The problems are similar enough that they appear to have the same form.